# Cable tv recorder

Tags: video

I would like to record the input to my cable box, for a period of 24 hours, for playback the next day. I would feed the output of the recorder back into the input of the cable box. Has anything like this been done?

Comment: That's really not technically feasible. The input to your cable box consists of hundreds of different signals. Also, many cable boxes have state, so you would have to restore your cable box to a previous state somehow.

Comment: Typically when a feed is recorded, you would be recording the data in raw formats. I have a quad tuner that records shows (4 at a time). A 30 minute show with commercials is about 1.5-3GB. Can you imagine the space required for 200+ channels.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Input' to your cable box is a very complex RF (radio Feq Read as GHz Band) digial signal and as such is for all intents an purposes impossible to record.  Even if you could some how record the signal the amount of data would be staggering.  Think about it, The signal contain upward of 300 cable some in HD.  There is no problem recording the output of you cable box all you need is tuner  and cable card (for access to digital channels) for you PC and you can record up to four channel at a time One possible is the Cetron Infinity put the are cheaper less capable options. Try googling 'Home Theater PC', Personal Video Recorder and Digital Video Recorder.  There are other non-PC solutions also, like Tivo or your cable provider should have a DVR option.